# UIWebView in tabbed view Thread 1:signal 1 SIGABRT

Tags: ios, xcode, webview

I have a problem with Xcode. When I start my App i get the Error:

> Thread 1:signal SIGABRT.

I get the Error in this Line:

```
       @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

In the FirstViewController.h I've got this:

```
     @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
     @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *myViewWeb;
```

And in the FirstViewController.m:

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad

[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *fullURL = @"http://google.de";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_myViewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I just ran into this exact problem.